# color in red if that not in good format phone/Lower case with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i look for check my macro if a good format (Lower case,longitude transform point in comma,format phone like xx xx xx xx xx) if not a good format color the fond in red and writing in white.

exemple:if i found the format in uppercase not in Lower case like: TRUE , and i found the format phone not like (58) 86 48 48 85 ,then ,if i found longitude with point no with comma like :1.56 SO you should color the background in red because are not in a good format

can someone know how

```
    ' Lower case Macro
    ' Loop to cycle through each cell in the specified range.

    For Each x In Range("N:AA")
        x.Value = LCase(x.Value)
    Next

    ' longitude Macro
    '
    Cells(AC, AD).Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
Function TelFormat(s As String)

    s = Replace(s, "(", "")
    s = Replace(s, ")", "")
    s = Replace(s, " ", "")
    s = Replace(s, " ", "")
    n = Len(s) - 2

    TelFormat = Format(s, "(00) ## ## ## ## ")

End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a few examples of the inputs and required outputs to help us understand your requirements?

Comment: @CLR  for example : if i found the format in uppercase not in tiny like: TRUE  , and i  found the format phone not like (58) 86 48 48 85 ,then ,if i found longitude with point no with comma like :1.56 SO you should color the background in red because are not in a good format

Comment: Your replacement isn't doing anything. See ".", Replacement:="." is identical. I think you mean longitude with "." instead of  ":" is incorrect format.

Comment: yes i mean  Lower case rather Tiny and the fond of column in red @QHarr

Comment: :-) that's ok.  No worries. This doesn't do anything useful at the moment: 
   Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="."

Comment: how please  @QHarr  correct my code on top ?

Comment: I am not clear on this longitude    :1.56 ? I think you want to check all telephone number formats in a sheet,  yes? I think maybe you also have some co-ordinate information in the sheet where you need to check those co-ordinates (longitude or latitude) have "." not ";" ? However, for the longitude I am not sure, maybe it is a language thing and you do not mean co-ordinates?

Comment: @QHarr   just I want to check the coordinates in a table of a sheet if they are in good format (upercase, format longitude and latitude with comma no with point, phone number under format: (xx) xx xx xx if not color the column of table in red that 's all.

Comment: Can you share a picture of your data?

Comment: @QHarr http://prntscr.com/ilcvpb this is a screenshot of my table which i want to check the format if not good format color in red cloumn. that's clear ?

Comment: :-)  @QHarr colonne is a column, ligne is a line and sorry i mean color a red for a cell which had  a bad format not a column as i said .that 's clear what i want to check ?

Comment: In your image I can't see any example of longitude/latitude which is why I wondered if you meant column and row for the table. Are you expecting co-ordinate data? Can you show an example of the exact expected longitude/latitude format?

Comment: sorry @QHarr http://prntscr.com/ilevff  this is a screenshot of longittude format when i check that had a bad format the cell become  red (good format :fill in with commas no point) how can i correct plz my code to become like screenshot.

Comment: Aha, so 4,5 good and 4.5 bad

Comment: yesssss @QHarr  :-)

Comment: Is colonne phoneActivite the only one where tel must be checked and changed?

Comment: @QHarr  no,just check and if it has a wrong format it becomes red like in screnshot http://prntscr.com/ilfzuq (the good format of phone :« 0X XX XX XX XX »)

Comment: @QHarr did you know how can i correct my code to check if it has the good format ?